# How can I upload this data on R?

Tags: r

I need to read the data in this link: http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~snijders/siena/ for my final assignment.
The problem I haven't seen these data extension before as the file name is like (cov1.dat) for example and I don't know how can I upload it on R.

So please need your help

Comment: if the link is not working: the name for the data set is (Description students data set Marijtje van Duijn ) in data set section

Comment: That link points to a text webpage. I couldn't find the cov1.dat. Could you provide a more specific link

Comment: yes and I dunno why, so you can find it in data sets section, and the name is ((Description students data set Marijtje van Duijn and data set ) )

Comment: Oh ok I'll give you a tip, next time you can right click on the link and copy it so you can paste it here. Like this: http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~snijders/siena/DataMarijtje.zip
I found it and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks for your advice 
waiting you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay when you find a file than you don't know, the first thing you must do is open it on  text editor such as notepad and see what it looks like. In this case, the file was plain text so it would be very easy to open with normal reading functions.

```
 1  1 1 2 1 21 29 34 13  8 25 42 42 42 42 42 42 34 4 2 3
 2  1 1 0 2 24 28 36  7  2 22  2 29 36 36 23 32 28 4 2 2
 3  1 1 0 1 24 21 13 42 34 21 21 29 25 21 29 21 29 4 3 3
 4  1 2 0 2 30  6 21  0 32 21 21 38 36 17 21 21 35 4 3 3
 5  1 1 0 1 38 17 29 40 29 34  1 21  4 21 38  0 25 5 4 3
 6  1 2 0 1 18  4 21 10 26  5  0 38 14 10  5  2 32 3 2 2
 7  2 2 4 1 37  6 15 23 19 23 26 18 18 32 27  3  7 5 4 2
 8  2 1 5 4 36 21 21  2  2 21  0 25 21 42 34 27 32 4 3 2
 9  2 1 0 2 27 21  6  0  2 36  4 10 34 21 21 29 13 4 3 1
10  2 1 0 2 27 30 18  0  0 13  6 19 21 38 22 34  6 5 4 5
11  2 1 2 2 24 21 27 40 32  2  0 15  4 32 30 11  9 4 3 2
12  2 2 5 1 38 34 29 17  4 13 25 25 21 38 34 25 34 4 2 2
13  2 2 0 2 37 21 32 38  0 34  0 33 25 38 34  0 29 2 1 2
14  1 1 0 1 32 21 27 36 36 21  3 36 21 24 34 31 27 5 3 2
15  2 1 0 1 17 34 25 42 25 17  0 21  4 29 29  0 29 4 3 2
16  2 2 2 1 32 23 32 11 23 23 27 23 21 23 23  7 28 5 4 2
17  2 2 0 1 26 30 31 30  9 13  4 34 31 40 34  9 39 4 2 2
18  2 2 2 1 29 32 21  0  9  0 41 41 29 40  0 10 34 5 3 1
19  2 1 4 4 25 21 19  6  0  7  0 42 21 26 36  0 22 4 4 4
20  2 2 2 2 29 25  6 26 21 22 12 25 17 21  8 29 13 4 3 2
21  1 2 4 2 25 25 29 24 17 17 17 24 20 38 29 13 21 4 3 4
22  1 1 0 1 29 29 16 42  0 21  8 38  8 42 21  0 21 5 3 5
23  2 1 0 1 21 25 25 13  0  4  0 34 21 17 25 17 34 4 2 2
24  1 1 9 4 38 38 29  8 34  8  2 42 34 34 38  0 34 4 3 1
25  2 1 5 5 36 31 31  2  2 11 27 40 28 19 10  3 23 5 3 5
26  2 2 0 1 28 21 21 36 16  0  0 21  3 13  7  0 16 5 3 3
27  2 1 0 1  3 13 21  4  2  4 42 21 18 13 21  0 42 1 1 1
28  1 1 0 1 27 11 27 40 34 32  7 32 25 21 32  0 21 4 3 3
29  1 1 5 5 19 23 31  6 11 14  7 28 25 36 34  0 24 5 3 4
30  2 1 0 1 13 29 29 21 17 26 22 42 21 34 36  0 21 3 2 2
31  2 2 4 1 18 32 28 34  6 11  7 33 10 28 32  2 37 5 3 3
32  1 1 3 3 30 25 25 21 13 26  0 38 25 34 30 25 30 5 3 4
33  2 2 5 1 29 26 34 21 13 21  0 34 17 26 26 42 29 5 3 5
34  2 2 0 2  9 28 28  7  3 28  0 26 28 32 27  9 21 5 4 3
35  2 2 5 1 34 25 30 14  9 30 34 34  8 29 31 26 30 5 3 2
36  2 1 0 1 30 26 21 17 14  9 14 30 21 40 12  4 30 3 2 5
37  2 1 5 3 41 41 37  2  6 28  2 41 21 38 36 11 24 4 2 1
38  1 1 0 1 17 31 21 29 10 29  0 34  8 21 21  0 21 3 3 2
```

I have used the common `read.table()` operation and it worked.

```
dat <- read.table("DataMarijtje//cov1.dat")
```

Comment: another Q please,
Do you know how if I want to transfer it to an R data file? and then can use load() function? in the future ?

Comment: I don't see the need to save it as a data file, since it is working now. But if you want to do it, all these functions have counterparts. load() and save(). So you read it with read.table(), save it with save(), so in the future you can use load() to read it.